# Does $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}^{\frac{1}{2^n}} $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does $\Sigma\frac{1}{2^n}^{\frac{1}{2^n}} $ converge?  I am using this to test whether $\Sigma\frac{1}{n(n^{\frac{1}{n}})} $ converges using Cauchy's condensation test.  I suspect that it does not converge because the exponent is not greater or equal to 2, by analogy to $\Sigma \frac {1}{u}^{\frac{1}{u}}$.

Comment: Direct comparison to the geometric series $r=0.5$?

Comment: @SeanNemetz  $\displaystyle \left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2^n}}  > \dfrac {1}{2^n}$

Comment: oh yeah... Sorry about that

Comment: Certainly not, since $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac 1n} = 1$$

Comment: Oh thank you,  I should have noticed x).

Comment: Each term becoming closer and closer to $1$ (if $n=20$, $a_{20}=\frac{1}{2^{5/262144}}\approx 0.999987$) , then, for large $p$, $S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n \approx p$. For example $S_{100} \approx 98.7751$ and $S_{1000} \approx 998.775$.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing MathematicsStudent1122's comment, we have $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac 1n} = 1$$.  Once your $n \ge 2$ the terms are greater than $\frac 12$ so the sum diverges.